# ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110

Tags: kernel, grub, boot-loader

```
[ OK ] GRUB failed boot detection.
[ 145.200501] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
```

System not booting up
Tried Linux 5.0.0-32 Genric recovery mode, what happened is attached in the pic.
[image]